# Proof about characteristic polynomial

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Suppose that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and consider the linear map $L_A : \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ defined as $L_A(X) = AX$. Show that the characteristic polynomial  (denoted by $\chi$) $\chi _{L_A} (t) = (\chi _A (t))^n$.

So I have no idea how to prove this. I know that

$\chi _{L_A} (t) = \det (AX - t I)$

and

$\chi _A (t) = \det (A - t I)$

But how can I connect this two informations... Can someone give a hint please?

Thanks!!

Comment: The notation is very imprecise. What is $t$? A scalar? So what is $L_A(t)$ Why in your equations you have $t$ on one side and $\lambda$ on the other?

Comment: You're right it should have been $\lambda$ instead of t. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone can help me?

Comment: Still I think there is something wrong. Shouldn't the first equation be $p(L_A(X))(\lambda) = \det (AX - \lambda I) $ rather than $p(L_A(\lambda)) = \det (AX - \lambda I)$? Notation is not an optional!

Comment: I agree with you... But the notation I wrote is the same one I saw in the original exercise, I took it directly... But the way you say makes more sense... Can you help me?

Comment: But at this point I  wonder what is it meant with $(p(A(\lambda))^n$... Why you don't erase this question and you reformulate it again in understandable way?

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: In a sense it is now more clear. But in a different sense it is worse. In fact, if I have correctly understood,  the statement is not correct. In fact you write $\chi _{L_A} (t) = (\chi _A (t))^n$. Now $ \chi _A (t)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ because $A$ is a $n$ by $n$ matrix. Also $L_A$ is a $n$ by $n$ matrix, hence the characteristic polynomial has degree $n$. But $(\chi _A (t))^n$ has degree $n^2$

Comment: But this is flatly the original question! So the question doesn't make sense, is it?

Comment: This is what I read. You wrote in practice: $\det (AX - t I) =[\det (A - t I)]^n$, i.e. two polynomials with manifest different degree are equal! This is what I can say

Answer (score 3):

This should be more seen as a hint: Consider $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, where the $x_i$ denote the column vectors of $X$. Now consider $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ as a "normal" vectorspace, i.e. with column vectors, then you have

$$ X=\pmatrix{x_1\\ \vdots \\ x_n}. $$

Now what is meant by $AX$ in this representation? Since the columns of the Matrix $AX$ are precisely $(Ax_1,\ldots,Ax_n)$ you get that:

$$ AX=\pmatrix{A &\ldots & 0\\
0 & \ddots & 0\\
0 &\ldots & A}\pmatrix{x_1\\
\vdots\\
x_n} \text{ i.e. } L_A=\pmatrix{A &\ldots & 0\\
0 & \ddots & 0\\
0 &\ldots & A}. $$ 
But now it should be clear, that $\det(L_A-tI)=\det(A-tI)^n$, note that on the left hand side $I=id_{n\times n}$ whereas on the right hand side $I=id_n$.